# AngularJS: one or many directives?

Tags: angularjs, performance, optimization, angularjs-directive

My problem: I have product object like this: `{id: 1, category: 'Television', price: '$2000',...}`, then I create `product` directive. User can buy a product by using `product` scope function `buy(quantity)`. But I have many products, create scope with this function for every product might be waste of memory? Should I create additional directive, `productBuyer` has method: `buy(product, quantity)`, then `product` directive `require: '^productBuyer'` will be put within it? Which design is better when application scales? Or is there any else way better?

More:  I don't put `buy` to factory because `product` has to display error message if buy fail (for many reasons: out-of-date product, product-warehouse is empty, don't deliver to user's location...), this process method is passed to `product` directive.

Comment: Are you going to have 100K-1M products displayed on a single page? No? Then, stop worrying about waste of memory.

Comment: @NewDev: thank for your comment. About design pattern, use one directive is better?

Comment: I don't necessarily think that using a directive that "buys" the product it represents is a good idea. Directives are self-contained and reusable bits of functionality. They _could_ connect to a service, but something like buying a product, your app would most likely be involved (e.g. cart, checkout, etc...). You could definitely attach a "buy" button to each directive, but I would place the buy functionality on the controller.

Comment: @NewDev: Your mean is place buy function on new controller or product directive controller?

Comment: @NewDev: sorry because I'm a newbie, your mean is create product directive to represent data only, no buy, checkout... functions. Then create a controller to do these things then place it in HTML like this: `ng-controller=SomeController`? If that so, it looks like use 2 directives like what I describe above, except outer directive is controller instead. Am I wrong?

Comment: In my opinion, since buying a product is not a self-contained action (like, say, loading an ad), then it's better to have the directive only deal with user actions and templates pertaining to it, and then use `&` scope property to callback functions on the hosting view's (not directive) controller. And yes - a single directive.

Comment: @NewDev: Yes, it's exactly what I want to ask. Use only one directive is compact, use 2 directives (outer and inner) is not waste of memory, plus convenient (one do actions, one render). Correct me if I'm wrong. Do you have other idea?

Comment: I don't immediately see a need for outer and inner directives. But... it's your design

Comment: @NewDev: I'm very interested in design approach. In my problem, `buy` function should be placed outside `product` directive, I mean in view controller? If that so, where should buy button be placed? In `product`? Can you give me an example, code...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would restrict the use of directives to self-contained and reusable bits of functionality. In your example, put common functionality in the directive, but keep functionality related to the broader app in the view's controller - not in the directive.

**app.js**

```
angular.module("myApp", []).
.controller("shoppingCtrl", function($scope, productSvc){
   productSvc.getProducts()
     .then(function(products){
        $scope.products = products;
     });

   $scope.buyProduct = function(product){
      productSvc.buy(product)
        .then(function(){ /* do something */ });
   }
})
.directive("product", function(){
   return {
      restrict: "EA",
      scope: {
         product: "=",
         onBuy: "&"
      },
      templateUrl: "productDirective.html",
      controller: function($scope){
         $scope.clickOnBuy = function(){
            $scope.onBuy();
         }
      }
   };
});
```

**productDirective.html**

```
<div>
  <div>{{product.title}}</div>
  <div>{{product.price}}</div>
  <button ng-click="clickOnBuy()">Buy</button>
</div>
```

**index.html**

Finally, in your HTML you can do:

```
<div ng-controller="shoppingCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="item in products" product="item" on-buy="buyProduct(item)"></div>
   <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! Now I have an other problem. If I don't pass `onBuy` function, I don't want to display Buy button. How can I do that?

Comment: Add `ng-if="onBuy"` to the buy button. It would render the button if `onBuy` is defined